# Interact with sftp (cygwin) from application on Windows

Tags: c#, ssh, cygwin, sftp, expect

On Unix you have tools like `Expect` and `Empty` for interacting with terminal applications like `sftp`, using pseudo terminals. I have a Windows machine with cygwin installed on it and my `C#` app needs to start an sftp session to transfer some files to a remote machine.

I started with some code like this

```
var p = new Process();

p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "sftp",
    UseShellExecute = false,
    CreateNoWindow = false,
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
    Arguments = username + "@" + server
};

p.Start();
p.StandardInput.WriteLine(password);
```

The problem is that `sftp` will not read a password from `stdin`, only from the terminal. That's where Expect comes in. Outside of installing `Expect` in cygwin is there any way to interactively send a password to `sftp` from a `C#` program?

Comment: Do you absolutely need to authenticate via password? Using public-key authentication might be less problematic

Comment: I agree it would be less problematic and we could set up password-less sessions but this is the way it is - have to support usrname/pwd interaction through code.

Comment: any reason you are not using a pure .NET sftp client (with all the options for authentication etc.) ?

Comment: @Yahia Is there a stable, production-quality free .NET SSH library that is OpenSSH compliant?

Comment: production-quality/compatible/stable are several, although the ones I worked with are commercial... free are for example http://sshnet.codeplex.com/ and http://www.routrek.co.jp/library/support/download/varaterm/granados200.tar.gz though I never used that so can't say anything regarding production-quality

Comment: @Yahia Thanks. I've had a look at them (and every other available option - free or paid) already. We're not going to use any of the free options because of quality concerns and we ain't going to buy any either. Perl, cygwin and OpenSSH are all going to be on the box already.

Comment: you will have your reasons to do so and I wish you the very best.

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin has [packages for tons of common UNIX utilities](http://cygwin.com/packages/), including [expect](http://cygwin.com/packages/expect) and (probably) empty. In theory you could still use those... (not that this would be the most secure, compact, or ideal option... but it's an option!)

Comment: Cheers, I did say "outside of installing Expect in cygwin" but this might be the way we end up going if there is no alternative.